# How to use @Binding to a class element in a struct in swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Sorry for the kind of a basic question.
I'm making a web crawling app using swift. Using webkit, I've succeed to load and displayed some page I want to. Because I need to crawl several pages, I need to check all pages are completely loaded before evaluate javascript.

next is the type definition of WKWebview that I've defined.

```
struct WKWebViewstruct: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: String
    let webView = WKWebView()
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            return WKWebView()
        }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        return webView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    //Show the progress
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WKWebViewstruct
        init(_ parent: WKWebViewstruct) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.parent.isLoading = true
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("Loading Started: Date: \(Date.now)")
            parent.isLoading = true
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("Loading Finished: Date: \(Date.now)")
            parent.isLoading = false
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that when if the site is completely loaded, than isLoading will change to false. After all the isLoading in different variable is toggled to false, I'll evaluate javascript. However, I cannot use this structure because I cannot initiate a variable of type WKWebViewstructure.

That is to say, when I define an @State variable and a variable of WKWebViewstructure like,

```
@State var IsLoading: Bool = true
let webView = WKWebViewstruct(url: "https://www.google.com", isLoading: $IsLoading)
```

It alarts an error which states that
"Cannot use instance member '$IsLoading' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

I've searched this error and it is like something initiate error that I cannot reference before the class is completely loaded.

How can I bind the variable that change in class. Do I need to use binding in class?(which is already an reference type variable;) Is there another method for the case?

Comment: You are supposed to create views in the `body` property of another view. Why are you declaring a `let` constant initialised to a `WKWebViewstruct`?

Comment: Also, if you are crawling pages, why do you need a `UIViewRepresentable` in the first place? You don't actually need to display the web pages to the user, right? Then this is your business logic, not your view.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for answering. My app reads html from website and parse the html using swiftsoup. To read html, I`m using webview.evaluatejavascript code, which requires the wkwebview is on body. So, I made wkwebview and made it 0 height with frame. There is no specific reason for using this weird method but just my ignorance. Are there any good method to do without using this weird method?

Comment: Yes. A `WKWebView` can load web pages without actually being on the screen, so you can just write a class that handles all this stuff, and make that class an `ObservableObject` or `@Observable`, so that you can interact with it in your SwiftUI code.

Comment: Anyway, your post is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] it to show some code that shows the problem you are actually trying to solve, namely running some JS code after all the `isLoading`s are false.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks alot! I'll definitely try the solution! ps. because the code is extremely long(>1500lines)  i trimmed some part. I'll gonna make it clear and edit this post. Thanks for your kindness

Comment: I also suspect that what you really want is a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser). You can try using a package like [this one](https://github.com/phimage/Erik) too, which might be more convenient.